# Android xml, how to get gradle parameter value

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I'm developing an Android app and I have to show the app's version, which is stored at the build.gradle file, at an xml layout, I want to set the value from the xml. How can I do that?

This is the content in my gradle file

```
android{
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2
        versionName "v2.0"
    }
}
```

I want to write "v2.0" in a textview, but I can't :(

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can use the value from your build files in the layout.

On the other hand, you can do it from the `Java` code, and you don't even need to use package manager for this. During the build stage `Gradle` generates for you the class called `BuildConfig` which has the `String` field `VERSION_NAME`, containing the value you provided in the build file.

So, `mTextView.setText(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can get this with the help of package manager:-

```
 PackageInfo pInfo = null;
    try {
        pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        String versionName = pInfo.versionName;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and then set the string versionName in your textview or view,wherever you want to use it.

as you mentioned you want to get if from your textview,do it as:

```
yourtextview.getText();
```

Comment: But i need to read the value from the xml, is it possible? like  android:text="@string/version_name"

Comment: No, i  dont want to get textview's value, i want to write the version name without java code, i want to do it from the xml. Thanks

Comment: you have to get the value from java code and then use the setText method,i don't think there is any method without java code